# How to make Oracle Query recognizable to ASP.NET table adapter?

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle, ado.net

I have a query with a sub query in the select that needs to get a value from a certain table if it exists.  I don't want to paste the query here for business reasons, but here's a simplified example of what I am trying to do:

```
select a, b, (select x from z) as c  from table where ...
```

The query runs fine in TOAD, but when I go through the ASP.NET table adapter wizard in my data object, it complains about the sql statement: "Error in SELECT clause NEAR ','".  I'm not sure if it would still work at runtime even though it complains? I know the preview doesn't work and it didn't create the data table.  Anyone experienced this?

The reason I want to do it this way is because the query that populates field c will not always have a value but I have to return a and b even if c does not have a value.  Any one good with knowledge of sql may be able to suggest a work around. I want to stick with 1 table adapter query if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outer join to table Z?

```
SELECT t.a,t.b,z.x
  FROM table t LEFT OUTER JOIN Z ON (t.y = Z.y)
 WHERE...
```

This will give you the values from Z if they exist, NULL otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

When a tool doesn't understand a query, one method that always works is to create a view that encapsulates your query.

```
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT a, b, (select x from z) as c from table
```

You would then use a simple query in ASP.NET like :

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM v where...
```

The view now contains your business logic and would be kept in your source control repository alongside all your other code.

Comment: +1, good suggestion as long as users have the ability to create objects in the database.

Comment: Unfortunately this would require DBA approval and regression testing.